# Logic Pro X: How to send input of bus1 to bus2?

Tags: logic-pro, production

My snare has two busses. Bus 1 is for echo and Bus 2 is reverb. When I play the snare track, the initially hit produces echo and is also reverberating, but the subsequent echoes themselves are not reverberating.

I tried changing the order and made Bus 1 as Reverb and Bus 2 as Echo, but that didn't change anything.

Is there a way for the echoes to also be fed into the reverb?

Comment: Are you sending the snare into each bus in parallel or in serial? Did you try routing the snare into the delay bus first (unrouting the snare from the Master), then routing the delay bus into the reverb bus (unrouting the delay bus from the Master)?

Comment: You can check whether it works or not by lowering the Dry mix in the Delay to 0, and maxing out the Feedback level.

Answer (score 2):

They should be, if you try it this way:

1. Route the snare sample into a Delay bus.
2. Route the Delay bus into a Reverb bus, if that is how you wish to do it. In that case, unroute the Delay bus from the Master track so that the only processed Delay signal is reverberated.
3. The Reverb bus should be routed to the Master track as usual.

To be sure that this works, try lowering the **Dry signal mix** inside the Delay plugin to 0%, and then max out the **Feedback level**. The "Dry signal mix" is the far right knob, and allows you to control what percentage of the output is the dry signal.

[image: Reverbed Delay on Snare]

(I currently have my cursor over the third knob from the left on *Fruity Delay 2*, next to "CUT", which is labeled the "Feedback level" on the upper left of FL Studio.)

This sounds like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59338379/reverbeddelay_snare.mp3

Alternatively, you could max out the **Feedback level** and keep the **Dry signal mix** as the default, but lower the **Dry signal input level** (second knob from the left on *Fruity Delay 2*). Then, the first hit would be louder than the delayed hits afterwards, and the delayed hits are still reverberated, since the "Dry signal input level" allows you to control how loud the input signal is.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however, the delay bus is also being used by other tracks and I don't want these tracks to have reverb. Does that mean I'll have to create a separate delay bus just for this snare? This was something I thought I could avoid.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a Delay instance onto the snare's own mixer track, followed by the reverb in the same mixer track? Is your delay plugin that memory-intensive that you feel the need to use a delay bus for multiple incoming sounds (besides for cohesion)? You can try the same test with the "Feedback level" and the "Dry signal input level" to check that it works. The separate delay bus routed into a separate reverb bus was just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Becuase I'd like to automate the delay using an automation envelope. I have delay on bus1 and I use automation envelope for that on various tracks to automate the delay. The send signal to this bus can be automated on LPX. Am I clear?

Comment: Here is an example. https://snag.gy/5psVSo.jpg

Comment: That's fair. But again, surely you have more than a few mixer tracks; you have room to create separate delay buses when you want unique processing on the delay wet signal. Since you have many instruments sharing your various delay sends, naturally if you want to reverberate only one specific delay wet signal, you'll have to serially place a reverb instance after the delay on a separate bus. If you place the reverb before the delay in the signal chain, like you could if you wanted to utilize the same delay bus, it'll echo the reverb wet signal, rather than the original sound's dry signal.